# Overriding Object.prototype.get to Prevent Null Check Issues in Large App

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, undefined

I realize this is not recommended by the JS community but I think have a good use case for overriding the Object.prototype so that accessing properties of undefined objects returns undefined instead of throwing an app crashing error.

Little background information:

1. Working with a large app (about 200k lines of code)
2. App is extremely configurable with loads of options - there's no way of testing every possibility
3. Angular 2/Ionic 2 project

Basically, I'd like to make it so that the following code console logs 'undefined' instead of generating an error:

Pseudo code:

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, Object.prototype.get, (val) => {
  try {
    console.log(val);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Attempted to access undefined property');
  }
});

const obj = {
  a: 'b'
};

console.log(obj.a.b.c); // should log undefined but actually generates an app freezing issue
```

Questions:

How can I make this work? Is there another way I can prevent null check errors across the entire app without adding too much code? Is there a generic fix for making it so that these null check errors do not crash the Angular/Ionic app?